# Use case for C #line directive

Tags: c, directive

I am reading some code written by someone else in C.

it goes like:

```
line 6: #include <map>
line 7: #line 8 "../myapp.h"
line 8: #include "users.h"
```

Whats the point of this? Is there any good/clear use cases for the #line directive?

Thank you for any insight.

Best

Comment: [#line Directive (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5w2czay.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #line directive is usually used by translators.

Let's say you have code written in some weird language, you use a translator translating it to C, and there is an error in your code so that the C code doesn't compile.

You don't care about the line in the C code where the error is, you want to know the line in your original code before it is translated. So the translator will most likely introduce #line numbers into the C code that match the line numbers in your original code.

Comment: That translator could even be the C preprocessor, translating from pre- to post-preprocessor C.